# Sum integers between two numbers with a recursive method

Tags: ruby, recursion

I want to sum all the integers between and including min and max with a recursive method. Example: `min = 1, max= 5, sum = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5`

My issue is that I can't find how to stop the "loop" created by the recursivity:

```
def sum_recursive(min, max)
   return min if                   #I don't know how to stop it
   min += (min + 1)
   sum_recursive(min, max)
end
```

I would have used a counter, but for this I need to create a variable which would be reset to its original value each time the function calls itself.

Is there a way to do this ? Or a different way to organize the method ?

Comment: `if min == max`. Also you should return `min + sum_recursive(min, max)` in the main case.

Comment: works for 1 + 2 +3 , but not for more. Even 2 + 3 + 4 doesn't work because I'm doing min += (min + 1) each time

Comment: BTW: The obvious arithmetic solution is of course `max*(max-1)/2 - min*(min-1)/2`.

Comment: @JörgWMittag yes but I was trying to use a recursive method. They are many to do this, even with reduce(:+) but it's not recursive

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should give a correct answer:

```
def sum_recursive(min, max)
   return min if min == max
   min + sum_recursive(min + 1, max)
end
```

The process is simple enough:

`sum_recursive(1, 3)` → `1 + sum_recursive(2, 3)` → `1 + (2 + sum_recursive(3, 3))` → `1 + (2 + (3))`